# OutOfMemoryError: Compressed class space

Tags: java, memory-leaks, java-8, out-of-memory, metaspace

I got this error:

```
 "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Compressed class space"
```

and until I'll figure out what's the trigger, I tried to 
disabling compressed class pointers with

`-XX:-UseCompressedClassPointers.`

but I still get this error. how is it possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compressed Class space is part of the metaspace.

Looks like your resolution is to either increase max metaspace size, or you may potentially have a leaky classloader.

Usually, this error is thrown when there is insufficient space to allocate an object in the Java heap. In this case, The garbage collector cannot make space available to accommodate a new object, and the heap cannot be expanded further. Also, this error may be thrown when there is insufficient native memory to support the loading of a Java class. In a rare instance, a java.lang.OutOfMemoryError may be thrown when an excessive amount of time is being spent doing garbage collection and little memory is being freed.

Comment: Some specifics would help e.g. show the options to increase the max metaspace size.

Answer (score 6):

This exception is explained in [Understand the OutOfMemoryError Exception](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/memleaks002.html):

> **Cause**: On 64-bit platforms a pointer to class metadata can be represented by a 32-bit offset (with `UseCompressedOops`). This is controlled by the command line flag `UseCompressedClassPointers` (on by default). If the `UseCompressedClassPointers` is used, the amount of space available for class metadata is fixed at the amount `CompressedClassSpaceSize`. If the space needed for `UseCompressedClassPointers` exceeds `CompressedClassSpaceSize`, a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` with detail **Compressed class space** is thrown.
>
> **Action**: Increase `CompressedClassSpaceSize` or you can turn off `UseCompressedClassPointers`. Note: There are bounds on the acceptable size of `CompressedClassSpaceSize`. For example `-XX:CompressedClassSpaceSize=4g`, exceeds acceptable bounds will result in a message such as *CompressedClassSpaceSize of 4294967296 is invalid; must be between 1048576 and 3221225472*.

Comment: Did you really mean, "Increase CompressedClassSpaceSize to turn off UseCompressedClassPointers.", or did you mean to say *or* turn off? That's how it would seem, from the rest of your comment. Just want to be sure, for future readers.