# How to Fix compressed class space?

Tags: out-of-memory, compressed-class

We are using open jdk 8 with spring boot version 2.2.4.RELEASE and embedded tomcat version 9.0.16 in our web application and since last 3 months we are frequently facing compressed class space issue. Every time when OOM occurs we have to restart application
The log found from catalina.log is below

```
ERROR org.jgroups.logging.Log4J2LogImpl.error:Line 95 - failed executing task FD_ALL: TimeoutChecker (interval=2000 ms)
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Compressed class space

788][2020-07-21 10:29:12,475]- org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.log:Line 175 - Failed to complete processing of a request
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Compressed class space
```

We have also allocated 2gb for CompressedClassSpaceSize using `XX:CompressedClassSpaceSize=2g`
as per some answer at [OutOfMemoryError: Compressed class space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35162542/outofmemoryerror-compressed-class-space)

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this issue by using one of the two options below.

**1. You can increase the limit of class space by using -XX:CompressedClassSpaceSize=n VM flag. Maximum limit is 4GB.**

(OR)

**2. You can completely disable Compressed class pointer feature by using -XX:-UseCompressedClassPointers VM flag.**

***Note:*** Please be aware that disabling this feature will increase heap space usage of your application.

In order to know more details about this OutOfMemoryError and class pointer(klass filed), you can read these books. It will provide you better idea of what you can really do with compressed class pointer and space.

[Java Performance Optimization: Compressed OOPS](https://javaperformanceoptimization.com/)